RSSH TUNNEL USING SOCKET FILE LISTEN | Error mux_client_read: reserve: insufficient buffer space
I am trying to setup a reverse SSH tunnel using socket listen. To establish the tunnel i am using

ssh -R /home/ubuntu/socket.file:127.0.0.1:22 ubuntu@10.0.4.3 -i
/home/ubuntu/.rssh/id_rsa

The connection is successful, and I can see the socket file created on my server 10.0.4.3.
However, when I try to access the remote server using the socket file with the command

ssh -vvvv -S /home/ubuntu/socket.file ubuntu@localhost

I encounter the following error and am unable to connect to SSH:
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
mux_client_read: reserve: insufficient buffer space
What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?
Reverse SSH Failing using socket listen
